# Swagger + spring global configuration

Tags: spring, swagger

Is there any way to configure swagger with spring globally so that swagger can automatically infer and generate the documentation by scanning the class / method signature without having to annotate each individual method with swagger annotations?

Comment: Do you use spring-boot or plain Spring applicaiton?

Comment: Plain spring application.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [springfox](http://springfox.io). You can generate service specifications without having to add any special annotations.

From the documentation describing the [goals of the library](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#goals):

> Philosophically, we want to discourage using (swagger-core) annotations that are not material to the service description at runtime. For e.g. the jackson annotations should always trump or have more weight than @ApiModelProperty or for e.g. @NotNull or specifying @RequestParam#required should always win. Annotations are to to be used only to supplement documentation or override/tweak the resulting spec in cases where its not possible to infer service/schema characteristics

Comment: Do you have any example? I could not find any without spring boot option?

Comment: Demos are available for a variety of options [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos). It has examples of spring mvc apps with xml configuration and java configuration in addition to the boot example.